# PHP Global Variable in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search my MySQL database based on a globalvariable but this is not functioning. Here is my code below. Ants hints will be appreciated.

```
if (!isset($Whatis)) {
    echo "Value for Whatis is not set";
} else {
     echo $Whatis ;
}
function PullOver($Monthselect) {
    $dateY = date("Y");
    $Valforthis = "select global $Whatis from graph where month = '$Monthselect' and year = '$dateY'";
    echo $Valforthis ;
    $retrieve = mysql_query($Valforthis);
    $Val = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve);
    echo $Val['$Whatis'] ;
}
PullOver('January');
```

Comment: Please don't use the mysql extension anymore.

Comment: You are defining the function within the `else`, therefore if `$Whatis` is not set, your function will not be defined and you will get an error.

Comment: In addition, when referring to a global from within a function you should declare it as global before you use it: `global $Whatis;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the 2nd line of the function `PullOver` to:

```
$Valforthis = "select ".$GLOBALS['Whatis']." from graph where month = '$Monthselect' and year = '$dateY'";
```

Answer (score 0):

When using global variables inside a function u need to use $GLOBALS

```
$Valforthis = "select global $Whatis from graph where month = '".$GLOBALS['Monthselect']."' and year = '$dateY'";
```

Sorry to link to w3fools but they have a pretty good example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp). Generally speaking people will tell you this is bad practice though and that you're better off just passing the info you need into the function.

Another option is to [pass the variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
function PullOver(&$Monthselect){...}
```